# Regular Expression for all entries that end with "n"

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I need to find a regular expression that finds all entries that end with `n`.

I'm dying here.

```
$ egrep '[.*n$]' computers.txt 
ST 314, Fox, PC, Unix
ST 13, Newman, Mac
ST 212, Frank, Linux, PC
BP 311, Jones, PC
ST 404, Walden, PC, Linux
ST 102, Christensen, Mac
ST 361, Lab, Linux
ST 333, Hu, Unix, PC
$
```

Above is my best effort and results

Comment: can you put some of the content of your file ?

Comment: When does an 'entry' end with 'n'?  When a word ends with 'n'?  When a line ends with 'n'?  Some other criterion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `[ ]` square brackets do what you think they do...

If you are looking for **lines** ending in an `n`, then;

```
egrep 'n$' computers.txt
```

If you are looking for people-names in the record ending in `n`, then it become a bit harder, but this will probably do;

```
egrep '[^,]*,[^,]*n,' computers.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the entire line entry, you can use the following:

```
egrep '\w+n\b' computers.txt
```

Output

```
ST 13, Newman, Mac
ST 404, Walden, PC, Linux
ST 102, Christensen, Mac
```

Or you can use the following to find only the entries that end in the letter `n`

```
grep -Po '\w+n\b' computers.txt
```

Output

```
Newman
Walden
Christensen
```

Comment: Yup. Tried grep as well. Same results.

Comment: Instead of the lookahead, use `\b` for word boundary (as in `grep -Po '\S+n\b' computers.txt`)?